# UI looks different in localhost and hosted website(GoDaddy)

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, web-hosting

I hosted my ASP.NET MVC website in GoDaddy, but the appearance looks a little bit different. My navigation bar that originally is black (the default of MVC 5), turns into blue. And my background image is not showing. What is the cause if this? Someone please help. Thank you. I already tried this for the background image:

`background-image: url('Image/BG30.png');` ---This one works in localhost, but not in hosted website

`background-image: url('/Content/Image/BG30.png');` ------Also works in localhost, but not in hosted website

`background-image: url('../Image/BG30.png');` --- This one doesn't work in both

Comment: Hard to tell w/out more info, but seems to me like maybe the approot is different in your local env vis-a-vis godaddy.

Comment: The css directories are always tricky. Try `Content/Image/BG30.png`

Where is your css "folder" placed, relative to your image location

Comment: It sounds like you have a problem with the direct path to your images. It depends where, you place your images in relevance to your HTML code

Comment: The path to your images has to be relative to the CSS file!

Comment: You can also try absolute path: background-image: url(http://www.example.com/images/bck.png);

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Thank you for the help Sir, but where can I see the approot? Sorry, I'm just a newbie. Thank you.

Comment: @mahatmanich Thank you for the help Sir. The background-image is in the default bootstrap.css. I tried the `background-image: url(Content/Image/BG30.png);` but it's not working in both localhost & hosted website Sir.

Comment: You should consider helping the community and "accept" the answer if it was sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Your reference to images in the css file must be relevant to the css file's location.  It might be a good idea to use absolute paths instead of relative paths. [This article](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/) offers a good explanation of when and why to use absolute paths.

**Relative:** /Content/Images/BG30.png

**Absolute:** http://www.example.com/Content/Images/BG30.png

**Example:**

CSS File: example.com/Content/styles.css

BG Image File: example.com/Content/Images/BG30.png

`background-image: url('Images/BG30.png');` would work because `/` and `../` move the path up to the root and up one level respectively.  `background-image: url('Images/BG30.png');` would work regardless of the correlation between the location of the two files.

It seems as if the hosted approot path differs from your local path.  Using an absolute path to your css file and absolute paths to your images (within the css file), can solve any confusion as to the location of the files.

You should also make sure that you're uploading **all** the proper files (images included) to the proper location on the hosted site.  Make sure that you're overwriting any existing files with the correct versions from the local path, this could be the cause of color issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help Sir. I'll try this. Is it okay if I ask your email account, for further questions? Cause I'm a newbie with this kind of stuffs. I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: If you require additional help on this topic, you can post comments here.  If you have different questions, please look for the answer to questions that have already been asked by using the search on StackOverflow.com.  If the answer cannot be found, simply ask another question.  Hope this helps!  Good luck.

Comment: Okay Sir. I understand. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: Indirectly mentioned, just here to clarify. When a relative path starts with a slash `/`, the browser will look for the file starting from the root of the site instead of looking for it relative to the CSS file when the path does _not_ begin with a slash.

Comment: Then you must not have all your files uploaded in the correct location.  The other thing you can check is the file permissions.